# Directory.GetCurrentDirectory

Tags: c#

I've written a program that checks if it is in a specific folder;
if not, it copies itself into that folder,run the copied program and exit.
but the problem is when I call
`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`
 in the copied program(only when It runs by the first one) I get the directory of the first program not the copied one.
What's the problem here?

the code:

```
if(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()!=dir)
{
      File.Copy(Application.ExecutablePath,dir+name);
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dir+@"\"+name);
      System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
}
```

i summarized my codes.

Comment: Your situation is quite convoluted. Are you sure the `correct` program gets the wrong folder? IOW, are you sure its the copied program?

Comment: "What's the problem here?" Aside from a funky design where the code insists on running in a specific directory? Why would you need to do this?

Comment: it's sth like keylogger. i need it to be in a specific folder. for example in c:\\ to act like a windows file.

Comment: Why do you want it to be in that folder? UAC might prevent you from moving your file there. For a very good reason. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i wanna make my program appear like a windows essential file. like filesystem or etc. so it should be in drive C. note that only the first times that the first programm runs it i have this problem

Comment: You are probably not copying the right files: File.Copy(Application.ExecutablePath,dir+name); The source files should be first. And you should use Path.Combine when concatenating file paths.

Comment: oh i said i summarized it. i meant "dir+@"\"+name" that name is sth.exe

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the WorkingDirectory on the processinfo, no need for copying the files.

```
if(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()!=dir)
{
  string exepath = Path.Combine(dir,name);
  ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  process.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
  processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;

  //Set your other process info properties

  Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
  System.Environment.Exit(System.Environment.ExitCode);
}
```

Comment: But is doesn't work. my program windows freezes with an error message.

Comment: Then give us the error message, we can only guess which isn't that much helpful.

Comment: It says that program is unable to continue and asks to close it or debug it.NOTE:it's not visual studio's error. it's from windows.

Comment: Show us the code and the error message, only then we will be able to help you.